# Limiting Daily Submissions into Database

Tags: php, sql

I am very new to coding and php so I realize this may not be the ideal way to code in order to accomplish my goal. My goal is to allow one submission per day into a table. I set a variable equal to a number. It then is supposed to query the table to see if there is a row that has the number and the session's user. If a row already exist with that number, I don't want any new information submitted to the table. If the row does not exist, I want the User and Number to be put in the table.

```
        $nd = '5';
        $nd = $td;

    $connect = mysql_connect("a","a","a") or die ("Problem Connecting to Database"); 
mysql_select_db("a") or die ("Can't find database");            

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * From p1 WHERE td='$td'");

$numrows1 = mysql_num_rows($query1);

if($numrows1 !=9999)
{
    while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
    {
        $dbtd = $rows1['td'];   

    }
            if ($dbtd==$td)
            {
                echo "You have already submitted Today.";   

            }
            else
            {


    $connect = mysql_connect("a","a","a") or die ("Problem Connecting to Database"); 
            mysql_select_db("a") or die ("Can't find database");
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO p1 VALUES('$name','$nd')");
            die("Submission Complete <a href = 'a'>Go Home</a>");


            }

    }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommend creating a date column (`date` type) with a unique index which will enforce one record per day.